# How do I get individual letters in an Alexa slot

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

My Alexa skill requires users to spell out words at times, so I to be able to have a slot that accepts individual characters. I've created a custom slot for this, with different values for each English letter and in my intent I've made multiple utterances using that slot from one occurrence to 10. However upon testing the actual application, Alexa is extremely dumb and doesn't properly get the characters spoken, sometimes returning a single character when 6 or so were spoken. Is there a better way to do this and why has Amazon not implemented an alphanumeric slot.

Comment: what ended up working out best for this? Did it ever really work?

Answer (score 1):

> Slot values are sent to your skill in written format. For example,
>   both "fire h. d. 7" and "fire h. d. seven" would be sent to your skill
>   as "Fire HD7". For better recognition, acronyms and other phrases
>   involving spoken letters should either be all caps ("HD") or separated
>   by periods and a space ("h. d. ").

In your custom slot, try giving sample values like this.

```
SPELL_SLOT
e. l. p. h. a. n. t.
t. i. g. e. r.
m. o. t. h. e. r.
c. a. n. d. y.
```

Give a wide variety of sample values to cover your requirement.

Hope this helps.

Comment: what if there are no specific samples I can give, because my skill allows a user to pretty much spell out any word?

Comment: As I said Give a wide variety of sample  including all alphabets and different combinations.